# Using npm for front-end dependecie or am I misunderstanding something?

Tags: npm, gulp, bower

I use the [Roots/Sage](https://github.com/roots/sage) wordpress starter theme, which uses npm, gulp and bower.

I wan't to use the [blueimp gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) in my theme.

Earlier I installed it with bower, but the new version of Bluimp/Gallery does not have `bower.json` file, and the creator of Blueimp/Gallery [says](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/pull/207#issuecomment-187003575):

> With the latest version of NPM and its support for flat dependency
>   trees, I don't see the need for bower anymore.

How should I install Blueimp/Gallery in my theme?
I tried with npm install --save blueimp-gallery, but now gulp did not complie the css and js of Blueimp into my main.js and main.css. Should I still use bower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use bower.
Edited my `bower.json` file, so it's build the files of blueimp/Gallery as well:

```
"overrides": {
    "blueimp-gallery": {
      "main": [
      "css/blueimp-gallery.css",
      "css/blueimp-gallery-indicator.css",
      "css/blueimp-gallery-video.css",
      "img/error.png",
      "img/error.svg",
      "img/loading.gif",
      "img/play-pause.png",
      "img/play-pause.svg",
      "img/video-play.png",
      "img/video-play.svg",
      "js/blueimp-helper.js",
      "js/blueimp-gallery.js",
      "js/blueimp-gallery-fullscreen.js",
      "js/blueimp-gallery-indicator.js",
      "js/blueimp-gallery-video.js",
      "js/blueimp-gallery-vimeo.js",
      "js/blueimp-gallery-youtube.js"
      ]
  }
}
```

I also edited my `gulpfile.js`, because the css of Blueimp/Gallery was looking for it's image in `dist/img`, but my gulpfile copied them to `dist/images` and `dist/fonts` (the svg's). So I added this line to the fonts and images gulp tasks:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist + 'img'))
```